# Asp.net core, redirect to admin login page when users try to access admin area

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

How can I ensure that when users enter localhost/Admin they are redirected to Admin/Account/Login instead of Account/Login using Asp.net core identity? I am using default template for authorization in asp.net core. Then I want to make sure that only users with role Administrator can login from there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. When user is not authenticated, how can the system know if they are admin or not?

Instead of 2 login pages - have a single login page, but upon successful credentials checks redirect users to different pages depending if they are admin or not.